# Jquery code not executing on elements that didn't exist on page load

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a web application that loads javascript on page load:

```
$(function() {
  $('.modal-delete').click(function() {
    alert();
  });
});
```

I have a html page with a series of buttons which alert a blank message box when they're clicked:

```
<button class="modal-delete btn danger"></button>
```

which works fine.

However, a have some AJAX calls that generate more buttons just like the ones above but NOT on page load!  They can be created at any time.  These buttons do not do anything but they're meant to load the alerts.  They're identical but because they never existed on page load, the Jquery code doesn't work on these buttons.  How do I attach the same code to these buttons too?

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want jQuery's 'live()' function:

```
$('.modal-delete').live('click', function() { 
  alert(); 
});
```

This binds to the elements which match but also rebinds when new elements are added in the future:

"Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future"

Comment: That depends on what version of jQuery you're using. jQuery 1.7+ should use `on()`, prior to 1.7 should use `delegate()`, unless you're using a very old version of jQuery (prior to 1.4.2), which is about the only time you should be writing new code using `live()` because you won't have either of the other options available to you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, pretty sure last time I looked was around v 1.4 (ish) which may explain my suggestion. As a side point, is there any advantage/disadvantage to each? or is it just naming convention/version preference?

Answer (score 1):

Change the ready code to this...

```
$(function() {
  $("document").on("click", ".modal-delete", function() {
    alert("click");
  });
});
```